# how to retrieve array of ids from facebook, using Graph API?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

This is NSString retrieve from facebook using me/friends, so I want individual images, so I can get by simply

```
http://graph.facebook.com/"id here"/picture
```

so how can I get array of ids from my friends, have any idea?

{"data":[{"name":"Abdul Basit","id":"508238854"},{"name":"Nasar Farooqui","id":"516100136"},{"name":"Ahmad Al-Refai","id":"525085450"},{"name":"Zamzam Shk","id":"100002088918788"},{"name":"Gm Jatoi","id":"100002187305416"},{"name":"Mohd Ali Khoso","id":"100002199757555"},{"name":"Shusheela Kumari","id":"100002282658638"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is JSON response...... you will need JSON parsing..... For this, either you can write your own parser..... or you can use exising one http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

thanks.

Comment: thanx for answer, but can you explain a bit more, a bit in detail, because it is huge concept and I need to understand it, please

Comment: You have to download framework and use its library file in your application......this link may help you ....http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/